# failure of alloc and Init

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

So perhaps this is a beginner's mistake and super easy to you guys, but i really do not know how to solve it,really appreciate for any suggestions:
Right Now:

1: I have to ViewController: EnterCommandViewController and DetectionViewController

2: I wrote Delegate protocol in EnterCommandViewController and set DetectionViewController as its delegate.

3: About delegate: I have a inputTextField in the EnterCommandView and a "Save" bar button item on the top toolbar in this view. Once I click the save , current view will be dismissed and return back to DetectionView and show the NSString just entered in the UILabel in DetectionView.

**Finally, My question is that Why After I alloc and init a EnterCommandViewController instance , that is enterCVS, the instance is still nil as show in end of my post.**

Code:

EnterCommandViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RscMgr.h"

@protocol EnterCommandDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void) commandEntered:(NSString*)command;

@end
@interface EnterCommandViewController : UIViewController    <RscMgrDelegate,EnterCommandDelegate>
{
    RscMgr* rscMgr;
    IBOutlet UITextField *inputTextField;
//    DetectionViewController* detectionViewController;
//      __unsafe_unretained id<EnterCommandDelegate> delegate;
}

-(void)sendMessage:(NSString*)message;

-(id)initWithDelegate:(id)delegateToBe;
- (IBAction)cancelPressed;

- (IBAction)savePressed;


@property (nonatomic,weak) id<EnterCommandDelegate> delegate;  //assign  replaced

@end
```

EnterCommandVIewController.m

```
#import "EnterCommandViewController.h"
#import "DetectionViewController.h"

@interface EnterCommandViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    @private
    BOOL connected;
}

@end

@implementation EnterCommandViewController

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
rscMgr = [[RscMgr alloc] init];
[rscMgr setDelegate:self];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[inputTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
-(id)initWithDelegate:(id)delegateToBe{
if(self = [super init]){
    delegate = delegateToBe;
}
return self;
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
inputTextField.delegate = self;
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
inputTextField.delegate = nil;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate Methods
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[self sendMessage:textField.text];
textField.text = nil;
return NO;
}


#pragma mark - Serial Tx/Rx Methods Implementation
-(void) sendMessage:(NSString *)message{
if(connected == YES) {
    [rscMgr writeString:message];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"CableDisconnected!");
    NSLog(@"Attempted To Send: %@",message);
}
}

- (IBAction)cancelPressed {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}

- (IBAction)savePressed {
//is anyone listening
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion] compare:@"7.0"    options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending){
    NSLog(@"SYStem version > 7.0");
    }
if(delegate&&[delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(commandEntered:)]){
    NSLog(@"SomeMethod is listening"); 
    [delegate commandEntered:inputTextField.text];
}
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //commened: ^{}
}

#pragma mark - RscMgrDelegate Methods Implementation
-(void) cableConnected:(NSString *)protocol{
inputTextField.text = @"cableConnected";
[rscMgr setBaud:9600];
[rscMgr open];
connected = YES;
}
-(void) cableDisconnected{
inputTextField.text = @"cableDisconnected";
connected = NO;
}
-(void) readBytesAvailable:(UInt32)length{}
-(void) portStatusChanged{}

@end
```

DetectionViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EnterCommandViewController.h"
@interface DetectionViewController : UIViewController <EnterCommandDelegate>{
}
- (IBAction)showSettings:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong) EnterCommandViewController* enterCVC;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *showReceivedCommand;
@end
```

DetectionViewController.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DetectionViewController.h"
#import "EnterCommandViewController.h"

@implementation DetectionViewController
@synthesize showReceivedCommand;
@synthesize enterCVC;

- (IBAction)showSettings:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
}

-(void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
if(showReceivedCommand){
showReceivedCommand.text=@"Initial text";
    NSLog(@"UILAbel in ViewDidload is not nil");
}else {
    NSLog(@"UILAbel in viewDidload is nil");
}
enterCVC = [[EnterCommandViewController alloc] init];
if(enterCVC.delegate) NSLog(@"X nil");
[enterCVC setDelegate:self];

}

#pragma mark - EnterCommandDelegate function(s)

-(void)commandEntered:(NSString *)command{

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(showReceivedCommand){
        NSLog(@"UILabel is not nil");
    }else{NSLog(@"UILabel is nil");}


    showReceivedCommand = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"command received: %@",command);
    showReceivedCommand.text = command;
   [showReceivedCommand setNeedsDisplay];
            NSLog(@"text in showReceivedCommand is %@",showReceivedCommand.text);
    });
 }
@end
```

I set a break point at DetectionViewController.n --> ViewDidLoad() -->   [enterCVC setDelegate:self];

I got:

```
self    DetectionViewController *   0x15c50e850 0x000000015c50e850
UIViewController    UIViewController        
showReceivedCommand UILabel *   0x15c510650 0x000000015c510650
enterCVC    EnterCommandViewController *    0x15c611360 0x000000015c611360
showReceivedCommand UILabel *   0x15c510650 0x000000015c510650
enterCVC    EnterCommandViewController *    0x15c611360 0x000000015c611360
UIViewController    UIViewController        
rscMgr  RscMgr *    nil 0x0000000000000000
inputTextField  UITextField *   nil 0x0000000000000000
connected   BOOL    NO  false
delegate    id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: What is the  RscMgr class? Also, which view controller is the initial view controller, and how do you go from the first one to the second?

Comment: RscMgr.h is another 3rd party library that I am using. the DetectionView is the initial view

Comment: And how do you go from DetectionViewController to EnterCommandViewController? Are you making these in the storyboard? Are you using a segue?

Comment: I have a bar button item(named "Settings") in toolbar at the bottom of DetectionView, which will segue (show) to EnterCommandView

Comment: This code is a complete mess. Please adjust, rewrite, etc. Doesn't make sense really...you are declaring making the EnterCommandViewController class be conforms to his delegate `EnterCommandDelegate`??! And then how these 2 view controller are allocated? seems that the delegate is gonna have some issue..that is a memory management issue.

Comment: BTW, the two views are in a storyboard file

Comment: You shouldn't be using alloc init to create an instance of your controller. The segue creates the instance. You should implement prepareForSegue, where you can get a reference to the destination view controller, and set yourself as the delegate there.

Comment: @Matteo Gobbi, sorry for the mess, just a minute, I will try my best to make it neat

Comment: @rdelmar , I did read some posts about prepareForSegue, So i just need to set the delegate inside prepareForSugue?

Comment: @rdelmar, so I should do that inside ViewDidLoad() ? Right?

Comment: Yes you do. That's where you get a reference to the controller that's created by the segue and is the one that appears on screen. The one you create with alloc init never gets on screen and is deallocated.

Comment: No, you implement prepareForSegue -- it's a method called by the system, you don't call it.

Comment: So when I do segue, both controller have been created automatically? since I need to set the property from EnterCommandViewController, I may need a reference of it, and set the delegate var in it as self.

Comment: Not both controllers. The one where you're implementing prepareForSegue (DetectionViewController) already exists. The segue creates the one you're segueing to.

Comment: That is the method. Do you have a question?

Comment: //Maybe:  EnterCommandViewController* en=(EnterCommandViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;                  en.delegate =self;

Comment: No, that's not correct. I'm sorry, I can't teach you how to program in comments. This is basic stuff that you need to learn from reading the documentation. I would suggest reading the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" and the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS".

Comment: Got you~Just found reference and finish it, works perfectly!~!~Horray!~! Really appreciate it!~~!~!~!~!~!~!~!~!

Answer (score 0):

```
enterCVC = [[EnterCommandViewController alloc] init]
```

Try changing that to....

```
enterCVC = [[EnterCommandViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
```